# If $S$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle ABC$ prove that $\angle BSD=\angle BAC$ where $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> If $S$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle ABC$  prove that $\angle BSD=\angle BAC$ where $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

I have tried a lot of ways but I have not been able to prove this. It would be great if you could give me a hint to solve this question.

Comment: We would like to know your 'ways'.

Comment: @tatan Sure..give me a while, I'll add them to the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $DS$ is the bisector of $BC$, but also the bisector of $\angle BSC$.
- Because $S$ is the center of circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, $|\angle BSC| = 2|\angle BAC|$, due to [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Got it! Thank you, didn't think of this :)